# Electron window corners without radius?

Tags: javascript, css, electron

I have an electron window with these properties:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  title: "Aqua",
  frame: false,
  transparent: true,
  show: false,
  fullscreenable: false,
  webPreferences: {
    plugins: true
  }
})
```

When I start it, everything works fine. But because my titlebar only shows on hover, I have an ugly edge on top and rounded edges on the bottom. I now want all of my corners to have a 0px radius. According to other resources on the Internet, it should automatically be 0px radius when the window is frameless and transparent. This does not work for me. How can I make my edges sharp with no radius on the whole window?

If you need my code, [here](https://github.com/matteo-piatti/aqua/blob/master/css/main.css) is my CSS, [here](https://github.com/matteo-piatti/aqua/blob/master/main.js) my main.js and [here](https://github.com/matteo-piatti/aqua/blob/master/index.html) my HTML.

Comment: what did u mean without radius?

Comment: I made this image to explain it simply. i hope you understand: [here](https://imgur.com/a/omDVf56)

Comment: by default windows have sharp edges??  what os are u on?

Comment: yeah I'm on mac. On windows default is sharp edges, on mac they are rounded.

Comment: damn wish it was the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I have found a hacky little workaround:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
frame: false, 
transparent: true,
  });


html {
  width:  /* less then window's size */;
  height: /* the same */;
  background: /* some color here */
}
```

This is hacky but the only way I found that worked. If you have a better way please still let me know!

You probably shouldn't use this. It may mess up everything!

Better solution: Just set a vibrancy and a transparent true in the creaton of the BrowserWindow, your window will be with hard edges. everything else will need to have a deep knowledge of chromium...

Answer (score 3):

Starting from version 13, Electron has a new `BrowserWindow` option called `roundedCorners` which can be disabled by setting it to `false`:

```js
const window = new BrowserWindow({
  title: 'A window without rounded corners',
  roundedCorners: false, // 
})
```

- [See all BrowserWindow options](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions)
- [See the original Pull Request](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/27572)

Make sure you are running version 13 of Electron or newer (check it: `npm ls electron`). If not, install the latest one: `npm i electron@latest`

Comment: electron 28, windows 11: `roundedCorners:false` is not working, even with `frame:false`. The 4 corners are still rounded

Comment: as in doc, it's for macOS only: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window

Comment: Use frame:false together with thickFrame:false should work

Answer (score 1):

Use `frame:false`, together with `thickFrame:false` should work on Windows. Use additional `roundedCorners:false` for macOS:

```
const Win = new BrowserWindow({
            frame:           false,
            roundedCorners:  false, // macOS, not working on Windows
            thickFrame:      false,
            webPreferences:  {}
        });
```